# Convert IP in text file to Hostname

Tags: python, networking

I'm trying to get hostnames using IPs from text file, but I'm unable to read all IPs from text file and the output shows only one IP.

Below is my COde,

```
import os
import socket

with open('ips.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.read().strip('\n'):
        ip = line.strip()
        b = socket.getfqdn(ip)
        print b
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in:

```
for line in f.read().strip('\n'):
```

this iterates over the whole file content (`f.read()`) without the trailing `\n`. Strings are iterables in Python, so essentially you are just iterating over each character of the text file.

Instead, as file objects are iterable, you can do the iteration line by line and get the relevant FQDN:

```
with open('ips.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ip = line.strip()
        fqdn = socket.getfqdn(ip)
        # print(fqdn)  # Python 3
        print fqdn  # python 2
```

Comment: Thanks for answering in Python 3, but since the question was in Python 2, it might be useful to the OP to mention that the parens won't be needed after the print statement in Python 2.

Comment: @PaluMacil Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Able to get it.

Comment: But the problem is if it find hostname it is printing, if it doesn't find host name for the ip than it stops there and din't go through other IPs in text file.

Comment: But the problem is if it find hostname it is printing, if it doesn't find host name for the ip than it stops there and din't go through other IPs in text file.